# TDD VS BDD: REST Service

Tags: ios, tdd, bdd, viper-architecture

I am all confused with TDD vs BDD :)
How does TDD and BDD differ in each of below point?

1. Development: Test case first, development follows next
2. RestService(HTTP): Don't make rest calls? If so,

   a) do we return only hardcoded json using a mock object?

   b) how to handle REST call failures? We should have test case for that too?

Especially for item 2, i have googled so many articles, but couldn't find a sample (code) approach on how to handle rest calls.

Answer (score 1):

BDD and TDD are not comparable to each other, although they are both used in test first development.

BDD is more than just writing tests with an English-like syntax, e.g. Kiwi. BDD (also known as ATDD—Acceptance Test Driven Development) starts with developers, QA, and designers (e.g. business, and interaction designers), working together to develop a shared understanding of the proposed solution. It is common to use examples to illustrate the behavior, also known as Specification by Example.

I have found that a useful way to think of abstraction is distinguishing between what you do (abstract, high-level policy), and how you do it (concrete, low-level details). Every concrete detail exists to fulfill a higher-level policy. When you see something concrete, it is beneficial to identify the policy it is serving.

The specification by example can be used to create high-level acceptance tests, which test what the application does, i.e. its behavior.

Unit tests are used to test how the app implements a solution, i.e. test that the appropriate messages are sent to its collaborators/dependencies at the appropriate time.

The phases of the standard TDD cycle are Red, Green, Refactor. During the green phase, your goal is to get the test passing as quickly as possible, by hook or by crook—it is acceptable to write ugly, unorganized code. Once the test passes, you refactor the code to make it more readable/changeable.

Similarly, with a BDD/ATDD cycle, you have Red, Green, Refactor. During the green phase of BDD, just get the acceptance test to pass. All of the code you write can exist within the test itself. During the refactor phase of BDD, you extract test code into production code. You can use TDD to guide the extraction.

So, for a given BDD acceptance test, you might have multiple TDD tests.

Regarding how to test REST calls, let's go back to the premise of abstraction—distinguishing what we do from how we do it.

Calling a REST service is a concrete action. The policy it satisfies may be to provide a list of model objects.

Let's say the use case you are implementing is to invite a friend to lunch. Part of the use case responsibility is to obtain the list of friends from a server; it doesn't care how the server finds the friends.

Your BDD tests would handle getting the list of friends, picking a friend, and completing the invitation. Your BDD tests would not worry about actually making REST calls.

When you use TDD to implement the the class that handles communication with the server, you could have tests that retrieve JSON from a remote data source (i.e. the server), and ensure the JSON is properly parsed into `User` model objects. You could also have tests to cover the data source responding with an error, etc.

At the point you actually make a REST call, in the implementation of a remote data source that uses REST to communicate with the backend server, I would classify that as an integration test, as you are testing the integration with a component you don't control, i.e. the actual backend server. The integration tests only need to confirm that the server returns JSON data in the format your app expects, or that errors are returned when appropriate.

Comment: BDD and TDD are completely comparable.

BDD is directly derived from TDD, eliminating the word "test" (see top link in my answer).

When you talk about "Acceptance Test" here, you're putting that word "test" back in... which completely negates the point of BDD in the first place! There's no such thing as a "BDD Test" - just examples and scenarios, possibly automated.

BDD can also be used for classes (the first BDD tool, JBehave, was originally intended to replace JUnit). It's more than just BDD = full system and TDD = class / module, though that's a common misconception.

Answer (score 1):

BDD is actually [derived from TDD](https://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd/), so it's not surprising there's a little confusion! BDD is exactly like TDD (or ATDD if you're doing it for a whole system), but without the word "Test". It turns out that can be pretty powerful.

Particularly, it lets developers have conversations with non-technical business people about what the system should do. You can also use it to have conversations about what a class should do, or a module of code should do, even with a technical expert.

So in the example of your REST service, you can imagine that I'm a dev and you're an expert who knows what the REST service should do.

> **Me:** What should it do?
>   **You:** It should let me read a record.
>   **Me:** Great! Can you give me an example of a record?
>   **You:** I have one here...
>   **Me:** Is there any context in which someone shouldn't be able to read the record?
>   **You:** Sure, if they don't have permissions.
>
> ...
>
> **Me:** Okay, so I've done Read, let's do Update. Can you give me an example of a typical update?
>   **You:** Here you go.
>   **Me:** Fantastic, and you want it to respond just with success or fail. Is there any scenario in which it *should* fail?
>   **You:** Sure. The record shows when it was last updated. If someone else has already updated it in the meantime, yours should fail when you submit it.

So you see you can use BDD to explore all kinds of scenarios, including those around a REST service. The trick is to ask, "Can you give me an example?" Then you get a concrete example, which you can then automate if you want to. The conversations help us look for *other* examples and scenarios which we might have missed.

Don't use BDD tools to automate for a technical audience! BDD tools like Cucumber, JBehave etc. work with real English that's a lot harder to refactor than code. Use JUnit, NUnit etc. if you're just doing something like a REST service. You can put "Given, When, Then" in comments, or make a little DSL.

So now you can see that with your REST call failure, if I were coding it, I'd have an example like:

> **Me:** So, this call failure... can you give me an example?
>   **You:** Sure, if you access a record that's been deleted it's going to fail.
>   **Me:** Give me a typical example of a record that might get deleted?
>   **You:** The one we're using before is good.
>   **Me:** Okay, is there a situation in which we shouldn't delete a record?
>   **You:** Yes, if it's already been published...

Etc.

You can see that throughout, I'm not really using the word "test". Tests are a nice by-product in BDD. It's used more for exploration and specification of requirements. The conversations in BDD are the most important part of it.

The reason it's tricky to find examples of using BDD for REST is first because REST is deliberately simple and doesn't often have a lot of behaviour, and second because BDD's scenarios aren't generally phrased in terms of their implementation, focusing instead on the value of what the service or system provides ("read a record").

TDD and ATDD are exactly the same, if they're done well. It's just easier to have conversations about examples and scenarios than it is to have them about tests.